# Slf4j or Logback: Turn off logging for 1 unit test (or 1 thread)

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback

I want to turn off logging for 1 unit test (which doesn't fail), so a stacktrace doesn't show up in the log. That stacktrace should be there in production runs because it's a failure-testing test.

The production code looks like this:

```
boolean failed = false;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    try {
        // Possible submits on Executor to run on other thread (not that it matters)
        runTask(i); 
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        // In the unit test, this pollutes the test log // BAD, MY PROBLEM
        // In production, it shows up in the log immediately, before other tasks run // GOOD
        logger.warn("Task failed. Stacktrace:", e);
        failed = true;
    }
}
if (failed) {
    // The unit test checks if this exception is thrown,
    // (it doesn't pollute the test log)
    throw new IllegalStateException("at least 1 failed");
    // In the real implementation, this also chains the first exception, to avoid eating the stacktrace
}
```

I have a unit test which tests that an executor throws an exception if at least 1 out of 10 tasks submitted to it fails. Because the executor can't fail when an inner exception occurs, it first runs the other tasks before throwing the outer exception. So when it catches the inner exception, it logs it, giving a stacktrace in the log. For QA, this is misleading, as the test logs show a stacktrace, despite that all tests succeeded. I want to get rid of that stacktrace in the test log ([jira](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-297)).

Comment: Wouldn't it be better in this case to catch the exception and not to print the stacktrace?

Comment: @SubOptimal The catch is in the production code, and the production code should log the stacktrace. In the inverse test "invalid-configuration-does-fail" for that production code however, I don't want that stacktrace logged (but in all other tests I do, because those aren't inverse tests).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might sound trivial, but have you thought about putting the logging call into an if-then block?

I'm pretty sure you pass the environment identifier to your application somehow (as an environment variable, for example). Now, it only takes a few minutes to create a utility class with a static method that decides whether the current environment is a testing environment or not.

Assuming that you can access the environment identifier as an environment variable, I'd go with something similar:

```
public class EnvironmentInfo {

     private static final ENVIRONMENT_IDENTIFIER_PARAMETER = "env";
     private static final Set<String> TEST_ENVIRONMENTS = ImmutableSet.of("test"); // this requires Guava

     public static boolean isTestEnvironment() {
         return TEST_ENVIRONMENTS.contains(System.getProperty(ENVIRONMENT_IDENTIFIER_PARAMETER));
     }

}
```

And when you log, you'd simply go with:

```
if (!EnvironmentInfo.isTestEnvironment()) {
    logger.warn("Task failed. Stacktrace:", e);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe there is no solution for slf4j as the supported frameworks might not support this function.

If you are using slf4j with a log4j binding you could achieve it as.

```
// get the logger you want to suppress
Logger log4j = Logger.getLogger("sub.optimal.package");

// keep the current level
Level previousLogLevel = log4j.getLevel();

// set the level to suppress your stacktrace respectively
log4j.setLevel(Level.WARN);
```

Find below an example how to configure the logger on method level. You need to have a different logger configured for which you change the logging level in production and in testing environment.

**assume following directory structure and files**

```
./Main.java
./slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar
./slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar
./log4j-1.2.17.jar
./prod/log4j.properties
./testing/log4j.properties
./bin/
```

**Main.java**

```
package sub.optimal;

import java.io.File;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Main {
    Logger logger;
    Logger loggerSuppressible;

    {
        logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
        loggerSuppressible = LoggerFactory.getLogger("loggerSuppressible");
    }

    public void doSomeFoo() {
        logger.info("logging from doSomeFoo");  
    }

    public void doSomeStacktrace() {
        try {
           new File("..").renameTo(null);
        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
            loggerSuppressible.error("something went wrong", npe);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();

        main.doSomeFoo();
        main.doSomeStacktrace();
    }
}
```

**./prod/log4j.properties**

```
log4j.rootCategory=info, console
# production setting
log4j.category.loggerSuppressible=info, console
log4j.additivity.loggerSuppressible=false

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.Threshold=info
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

**./testing/log4j.properties**

```
log4j.rootCategory=info, console
# testing setting
log4j.category.loggerSuppressible=fatal, console
log4j.additivity.loggerSuppressible=false

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.Threshold=info
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

**compile**

```
javac -cp ${classpath_logger} -d bin/ Main.java
```

** run in production**

```
java -cp bin/:prod/:${classpath_logger} sub.optimal.Main
```

** run in testing**

```
java -cp bin/:testing/:${classpath_logger} sub.optimal.Main
```

**output production**

```
2015-03-05 14:09:50,707 [main] INFO  sub.optimal.Main  - logging from doSomeFoo
2015-03-05 14:09:50,707 [main] ERROR loggerSuppressible  - something went wrong
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.File.renameTo(File.java:1386)
        at sub.optimal.Main.doSomeStacktrace(Main.java:22)
        at sub.optimal.Main.main(Main.java:32)
```

**output testing**

```
2015-03-05 14:09:50,847 [main] INFO  sub.optimal.Main  - logging from doSomeFoo
```

Comment: This would still affect other unit tests that run in parallel.

Comment: If you really need this functionallity on a method level, than create a unique logger for this method `Logger.getLogger("suppress.in.test");`.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet Please have a look at the complete example.